# Getting warning while adding noLayout prop to custom routes list in react-admin

Tags: react-router-dom, react-admin

How to remove following warning or any alternative way to add custom routes in react-admin without default appLayout?

> Warning: You should not use `<Route component>` and `<Route render>` in
>   the same route; `<Route render>` will be ignored

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import restProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Admin
        title="react-admin"
        dataProvider={restProvider('http://localhost:3000')}
        customRoutes={[<Route exact path="/custom" component={()=><div>Custom page without layout</div>} noLayout /> ]}
      >
        <Resource name="test" list={() => <div>Test Resource</div>} />
      </Admin>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use children instead of component in your route:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Admin
        title="react-admin"
        dataProvider={restProvider('http://localhost:3000')}
        customRoutes={[<Route exact path="/custom" noLayout><div>Custom page without layout</div></Route>]}
      >
        <Resource name="test" list={() => <div>Test Resource</div>} />
      </Admin>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is it possible to have access to `this.props.match.params` from within the inner component?